# How to Get data in mutiple @ManyToMany in Nest.js

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have a `ManyToMany` relation between two entities and I don't know how can I Get data from the join table "device_users_user"

```
@Entity()
export class Device{

  @PrimaryColumn()
  Name:string;


  @Column({ nullable: true})
  Port:number;

  @Column({ nullable: true})
  IPadress:string;

  @Column({ nullable: true})
  Location:string;

  @ManyToMany(type => User)
    @JoinTable()
    users: User[];

  }
```

```
@Entity()
export class User{

  @PrimaryColumn()
  Id:number;
  @Column({ nullable: true})
  Departement:string;
  @Column({ nullable: true})
  FirstName:string;
  @Column({ nullable: true})
  LastName:string;
  @Column({ nullable: true})
  CardNumber:string;
  @Column({ nullable: true})
  MobilePhone:string;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot query the join table directly, using the TypeORM API's (unless you try to do a raw query, but I assume this is not what you want to achieve... And I don't recommend it, as table names might be changed...).

However, as you declared the relation using `@ManyToMany`, you can load the `users` of your `devices` with a Query Builder, for instance:

```js
  const devicesWithUsers = await deviceRepository.createQueryBuilder('device')
    .leftJoin('device.users', 'user')
    .where(/* whatever you need */)
    .getMany();
```

The [documentation of TypeORM](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/select-query-builder.md#joining-relations) gives more examples, e.g.:

```js
  const user = await createQueryBuilder("user")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("user.photos", "photo")
    .where("user.name = :name", { name: "Timber" })
    .getOne();
```

which could gives, as a result:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Timber",
    photos: [{
        id: 1,
        url: "me-with-chakram.jpg"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        url: "me-with-trees.jpg"
    }]
}
```

Comment: and how can I delete a device or a user from a device ?

Comment: You can use `save` on the `device` (e.g. `deviceRepository.save(device)`) **after** you removed the `User` from the array of `users`. But that's not a super nice way to do it, as it requires to first do it in JavaScript (remove the user from an array). You can also do, with a QueryBuilder `qb`: `qb.relation('users').of(device).remove(userToDelete)`.

Comment: can you explain more please

Comment: You can delete a device by doing `deviceRepository.delete` or `deviceRepository.remove` (refer to the docs of typeorm). You can delete a User from a Device in two ways: Either by fetching the `Device` with its array of `User` (just like I said in my answer), removing a user from `device.users` and then using `deviceRepository.save(device)`... Either by using QueryBuilder `relation('users').of(yourDeviceObject).remove(idOfUserToDelete)`